# Add new line in chronoevent with chronosys

Tags: line-breaking, timeline, chronosys

I'm creating a timeline using chronosys package but I have some issue adding a new line inside a chronoevent.

Example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\section{Timeline}
\startchronology[startyear=2005, stopyear=2023, height=1ex, color=blue, arrowcolor=blue, dates=false]
\chronoevent[markdepth=150pt, datesstyle=\footnotesize, textstyle=\it \footnotesize, barre=false, datesseparation=/, conversionmonth=false]{07/2005}{test1\\test2}
\chronoevent[markdepth=180pt, datesstyle=\footnotesize, textstyle=\it \footnotesize, barre=false, datesseparation=/, conversionmonth=false]{12/2009}{test3\\test4}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

[image]

The keyword `\\` is not working and I'm not able to create a new line.
I tried with `\newline` as well with no success.
Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I edited the question adding the output of the code snippet as reference. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't  been asked to post a picture of the output but to post a *complete* code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please give new users time to respond before down-voting their questions.

Comment: @campa sorry about the confusion, now the question contains the complete code.

Comment: @cfr thanks for caring.

Comment: `chronosys` is notoriously hard to customise. If the change is supported by `chronosys`, the documentation seems good with clear explanations and useful examples. If the change you want isn't supported by `chronosys` itself, you really have two realistic options: (1) contact the author or (2) use something other than `chronosys`. In other cases, the package author has proved helpful and responded to such requests positively e.g. by providing custom versions of the package. Obviously, how able the author is to do that will depend on the change and the author's circumstances at the time.

Comment: Off-topic: don't load `inputenc` since you're using `fontspec`. You don't need `color` or `xcolor` as `tikz` loads this stuff anyway. You don't need `tikz` either because it is obviously loaded by your class. If it weren't, you couldn't load libraries before loading `tikz`. `hyperref` should be loaded last except for specific packages which you know require later loading. `\RequirePackage` isn't intended for use in the preamble and you've already told LaTeX to load `xcolor` at least three times.

Comment: @cfr yep I totally get your point but I left the includes I'm using for other purposes (not for timelines) and I removed the rest of the document content in order to not share sensitive information. I can work on a minified document content.

Comment: @neoben The points I made aren't about minimising your example. They apply to your real document. No matter what the contents, you don't need to load the same package multiple times, you shouldn't use conflicting packages and `hyperref` needs to be loaded late. As far as minimising the example is concerned, you could drop other things, too e.g. `smartdiagram`, but I assumed you needed those in your real document.

Comment: I edited the code leaving only the strictly needed code. Thanks.

Comment: @cfr got the point and I agree, you are totally right! I removed the useless (or wrong) stuff from my doc and I posted a new version. The issue persists. Thanks!

Comment: @cfr unfortunately I have not received any feedback from the author so I think I need to find a different solution with another package. Thanks.

Comment: My output doesn't match yours when I compile your code. I guess you have some special definition for sections, which doesn't really matter, but also the colours look different.

Comment: Yes I have some customizations about colors and style.

Answer (score 0):

You might, if you are feeling intrepid, try `chronos`. This is an ***experimental*** package and not currently on CTAN. It is based on my answers on TeX SE and some other code I used for timelines.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

Looking just-like-chronosys-but-tweaked isn't `chronos`'s default, but it is quite configurable.

The following example reproduces the MWE from the question and then illustrates a version using `chronos` rather than `chronosys`. The code uses `showframe` to mark the page layout. Note that the original timeline extends into the margin.

The example demonstrates one way to get multiline texts with `chronos`, using explicit `\\` s. An alternative would be to specify `text width` and let the content be automatically split accordingly.

Note that two-letter font commands are seriously obsolete in LaTeX and ought not be used. Depending on your class, they may even give errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701756/ i gwestiwn neoben: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699595/
% https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos
\usepackage{chronos}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\texttt{chronosys}

\startchronology[startyear=2005, stopyear=2023, height=1ex, color=blue, arrowcolor=blue, dates=false]
\chronoevent[markdepth=150pt, datesstyle=\footnotesize, textstyle=\it \footnotesize, barre=false, datesseparation=/, conversionmonth=false]{07/2005}{test1\\test2}
\chronoevent[markdepth=180pt, datesstyle=\footnotesize, textstyle=\it \footnotesize, barre=false, datesseparation=/, conversionmonth=false]{12/2009}{test3\\test4}
\stopchronology


\centering

\begin{chronos}
  [
    off line simple,
    timeline={%
      dates=2005:2023,
      timeline width=\linewidth,
      timeline height=1ex,
      timeline years=none,
      timeline foreground=blue,
    },
    every event below,
    event={%
      date format={!m/!Y},
      text tag+={%
        font=\normalsize\rmfamily\itshape,
      },
      date font=\footnotesize\upshape,  
    },
  ]
  \chronosevent{date=2005-07,name=t1,name content={test1\\test2},yshift=-150pt}
  \chronosevent{date=2009-12,name=t2,name content={test3\\test4},yshift=-180pt}
  \chronosmaintitle{name=\texttt{chronos}, at=chronos end, yshift=-10mm, anchor=north east}
\end{chronos}

\end{document}
```

[image: chronosys and chronos with marked page layout]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to integrate chronos on Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com) and give it a try.
I tried also the approach of changing "text width" but this will affect all the lines and i would like to have one line longer or shorter than the other.
Thank you!

Comment: @neoben In `chronos`, you could specify `text width` on a per event basis, if you really wanted to. I don't know if that's possible in `chronosys`.